# Transformation of Graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, mathematical-physics, linear-transformations

[image]

Hello all, I tried to solve this transformation and my answer was $-(x+3)^3+2$

my reason for thinking:

reflect cubic power, shift to the left $3$ units, move up $2$ units. $-(x+3)^3+2$

However, the correct answer it gives me is $-.5(x+3)^3+2$ , could anyone help me understand where the $.5$ comes in? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Note that $$(-1,-2)$$ lies on the graph. Your equation gives $$f(-1) = -(-1+3)^3+2 = -6$$However the correct answer gives $$f(-1) = -\frac{1}{2}(-1+3)^3+2 = -2$$

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain how the -1/2 is now before (-1+3)^2 and how it became squared instead of cubic?

Comment: The square was a mistake, it should be a cube.

Comment: A general transformation of the cubic $ y = -x^3$ can be given by $$ y = -a(x+b)^3 + c$$ The $a$ terms is responsible for squashing/elongating the graph.

Comment: Ok, I understand how we get to the final answer once we have the -1/2 as A. but how does one find A in this equation?

Comment: You already know $b= 3$ and $c = 2$, and you know a point that lies on the graph, namely $(-1,-2)$. So we are trying to solve $$-2 = -a(-1+3)^3+2$$ Which we get from plugging in $x = -1, y = -2$.

Comment: Ah thanks I understand it now. I appreciate it! +1